# Multiple threads with multiple cron expression on Quartz framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I have in my java project an Injector class thats read data from a data source and next uploads it to a DB.

I'm using Quartz framework to set a cron expresion for my injector class. 
Now, I have a single Injector executed.

How can I have multithread injectors where each one has it`s own cron expresion. Is it possible on Quartz framework?

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from your problem, having multiple quartz jobz may not be the solution.

What about you manage your multithreaded need inside your Injector class ?

This way, you develop the exact wanted behavior for reading and writing in multiple threads.

Java offers everything that you need for multithreading :)